# Why I can't use XPath to query the required node?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Here is the XML:

```
<VDWSDirectoriesResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Success>true</Success>
<TotalResult>6</TotalResult>
<PageResult>6</PageResult>
<Summary/>
<DirectoriesResult>...</DirectoriesResult>
</VDWSDirectoriesResult>
```

I would like to get the `Success` node, I tried `/VDWSDirectoriesResult/Success` or `Success`, but I still can't get the value of `Success` node...What Did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root node declares a default namespace:

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
```

This means, your `<Success>` node is actually in that namespace, and not in the anonymous namespace assumed by XPath if you just write `Success` in your XPath expression.

Depending on the XPath library you are using, there will be some way of mapping a namespace prefix to the namespace URI `http://tempuri.org/`, which you can then use in your XPath expression.

For example, let's assume that you map the namespace prefix `tmp` to that URI, your XPath should read:

```
/tmp:VDWSDirectoriesResult/tmp:Success
```